# Citing data taken from a data compilation

Tags: citations, data

The authors of a review paper have compiled about 50 measurements of the same quantity, each of them produced by a different experiment. They have included a table with all those measurements in a publication.

Q: If I want to use those 50 data points in a new publication, who should I cite as a source of the data points that I use: the original 50 publications, the review, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no right or wrong on this. If the review is an official publication, you're safe to use it. It's more about citation econonmy. If you'll quote the review, you save space in your paper.

A footnote added to the citation like "I use 50 datasets which are quoted there" adds transparency. However, I strongly suggest that you'll check thoroughly the correct citation of the quoted data sets in that review. In my 7+ year research experience I found that sometimes researchers wrongly relied on the thoroughness of others, which was actually lacking.